# What is the spring way to autowire factory created instances?

Tags: java, spring, autowired

I have a controller which is supposed to create version dependend instances (currently not implemented).

```
@Controller
public class ReportController {

    @Autowired
    private ReportCompFactory       reportCompFactory;

         public ModelAndView getReport() {
            I_Report report = reportCompFactory.getObject();
                      ^^^^^<- no autowiring in this instance 
         }
     ...
}
```

The Factory looks like this:

```
@Component
public class ReportCompFactory implements FactoryBean<I_Report> {

    @Override
    public I_Report getObject() throws BeansException {
        return new ReportComp();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getObjectType() {
        return I_Report.class;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSingleton() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The created instances fields (@Autowired annotated ) are not set.
What should I do, is FactoryBean the right interface to implement?

I would prefer a solution which doesn't involve xml-configurations.

The component itself:

```
    ReportComp implements I_Report {

        @Autowired
        private ReportDao           reportDao;
                                     ^^^^^^^<- not set after creation
    ...
    }

}
```

Comment: @irreputable has a question for you below my answer; not sure if you are notified about it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Spring doesn't perform autowiring if you create your objects. Here are a few options

- define the bean to be of scope `prototype` - this will make the factory redundant (this is applicable in case you simply want instantiation in the factory)
- inject the `ReportDao` in the factory, and set it to the `ReportComp` via a setter
- inject `ApplicationContext` in the factory and do `ctx.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory().autowireBean(instance)`

Comment: @stacker I'm interested in learning which solution you picked?