# Failed to Autowire beans in a Java thread in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, autowired

I successfully autowired beans and sent emails in my previous code. The code is as follow:

```
public class HomeController{
    @Autowired
    private MailConstructor mailConstructor;

    @Autowired
    private JavaMailSender mailSender;

    ...
    String token = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    String appUrl = "http://" + request.getServerName() + ":" + request.getServerPort() + request.getContextPath();
    SimpleMailMessage newEmail = mailConstructor.constructResetTokenEmail(appUrl, request.getLocale(), token, user);

    mailSender.send(newEmail);
    ...
}
```

Now I want to send the email in a new thread and I wrote my code referring to this link:[Why does Autowiring not function in a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7405232/why-does-autowiring-not-function-in-a-thread)
My new code is as follow:

```
public class EmailUtility {
@Autowired
private JavaMailSender mailSender;


public static SimpleMailMessage constructNormalEmail(String text, String subject, String toAddress, String fromAddr) {
    SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();
    email.setTo(toAddress);
    email.setSubject(subject);
    email.setText(text);
    email.setFrom(fromAddr);
    return email;
}

public class SendEmail implements Runnable{
    private String subject;
    private String text;
    private String toAddr;
    private String fromAddr;

    public SendEmail(String subject, String text, String toAddr, String fromAddr){
        this.subject = subject;
        this.text = text;
        this.toAddr = toAddr;
        this.fromAddr = fromAddr;
    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        SimpleMailMessage email = constructNormalEmail(text, subject, toAddr, fromAddr);
        mailSender.send(email);
    }
}
}
```

But I got the following error:

```
exception in thread "Thread-5" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Both this error and the message presented by IntelliJ **Could not autowire. No beans of 'JavaMailSender' type found** indicates that the autowire fails.

What may be the cause of this error and how can I autowire a bean in a thread? Any suggestion will be appreciated.

=============================UPDATE=====================================
Solved this problem with the help of these guys. The problem is that I create the EmailUtility myself.
MY previous code is as follow:

```
//Wrong Version
Thread sendEmailThread = new Thread(new EmailUtility().new SendEmail(subject, text, toAddress, fromAddress));
```

If I let Spring autowires the EmailUtility, then the code works:

```
//Correct Version
@Component
public class EmailUtility {
......
}

public class HomeController{

     @Autowired
     private EmailUtility emailUtility;
     ...
     Thread sendEmailThread = new Thread(emailUtility.new SendEmail(subject, text, toAddress));
     ...
}
```

Comment: You are constructing object yourself -> `SimpleMailMessage email = new SimpleMailMessage();` thus Spring is unaware of this object, it is not Spring bean anymore. Let Spring create the object.

Comment: are you sure that HomeController and EmailUtility are being scanned? They do not have annotations

Comment: Are your classes Spring components to be scanned by Spirngboot?

Comment: I agree with most of the answers here. It is a common mistake for people new to Spring. Made the same mistake too a couple of years back.

Comment: I solved the problems with all your help. The problem is that I create 
 the EmailUtility  by myself.```Thread sendEmailThread = new Thread(new EmailUtility().new SendEmail(subject, text, toAddress, fromAddress));```. Autowiring the EmailUtility solves this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EmailUtility` most probably is not created by Spring, since it is not marked as `@Service`, `@Component`, `@Controller`, `@Inject`, etc. thats why Spring framework has no chance to inject (autowire) your implementation of `JavaMailSender` into `EmailUtility` instance.

Spring does some magic with classes named by a certain pattern, therefore your `*Controller` classes might be recognized by Spring as beans, but not `*Utility` class.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your `EmailUtility` is not a spring managed bean. Consider adding annotation `@Component` to `EmailUtility` or declare a corresponding bean in your configuration class.