# How to pass Spring context as a method argument?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I need some help with Spring (SpringBoot 1.3.2.RELEASE, Spring 4.3.11.RELEASE).
Use case is special and need explanations.

I've got a Spring app managing requests send by customers. In order to process these requests, we need to use services declared with @Autowired annotation. Very classic.

Recently, we decided to process new types of requests from other countries.
The point is that to face the different cases and types of requests, we decided to implement a Strategy Pattern.
-> Depending on the type of request, we execute a strategy which is selected at run time. Each strategy is contained in a concrete class and all strategies share a same Interface.

So, I had :

- a main class in which requests processing was completely done. To do its job, this class used to call somes services declared with @Autowired annotation.

Now I have :

- a main class in which requests processing is only initialized. To do
  its job, this class will instantiate at runtime a single strategy depending on some criterias.
- a IStrategy (interface) with 2 methods thats will be implemented
  by my 2 concrete classes
- 2 concrete classes (and more to come) that will do the job. **The very important point is that these concrete classes will be instantiated at runtime, AFTER the Spring context is loaded.**

The problem is that after the Spring context is loaded, it's not possible anymore to use the @Autowired annotation.
**All services I wanted to use in my concrete strategy classes can not be called by @Autowired any more and remain NULL.**

I found a workaround by passing services I need as argument to my concrete strategy classes, but the number of services I have to pass as argument vary from one strategy to another.

I think I should pass the whole Spring context instead but I don't know how to do that. And I also don't know how I could access to all annotated services from the context.

PS : I do not show lines of code because I think there's no need actually. If you consider it would be more explicit with code, I will send some.

Thanx by advance.

Comment: You might want to define an own registry service where new implementations are registered and can be lookedup at runtime. Instead of injecting the strategies directly, you inject the registry service which you can use to retrieve the actual strategy. How the registry service maintains the strategies is up to you and an implementation detail.

Comment: Create something like a `ServiceProvider` which has all possible services wired into it (map, list, whatever).  Then the provider is injected into the controller and invoked to get the relevant service to be used:  `serviceProvider.getService(requestContext).execute(...)`;

Comment: maybe this answer can be of help to you https://stackoverflow.com/a/6596801/7634201

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello to all of you who answered me very quickly.
First of all, I have to apologize for answering so lately to all your comments. Last sprint was a big load and the new one is not better ^^

My need was to create on object after the Spring context has finished to create and load all parts of the app.
As part of a Strategy pattern, I have to instanciate a class at runtime depending on some values found in the request file I have to process. This class needs many services declared with the `@Autowired` annotation, but all the autowired objects remained '`null`' because called after the context was loaded.

Here is the code I first wanted to use.
It was OK without Spring.

```
Function<Document, IStrategy> func = doc -> {
        String strategyToApply = "";
        IStrategy strategy = null;
        switch(doc.getPlace()) {
            case "Paris":
                strategyToApply = "strategies_classes.ProcessParis";
                break;
            case "New York":
                strategyToApply = "strategies_classes.ProcessNewYork";
                break;
            }
            case "Roma":
                ...
        try {
            **Class<?> classToUse = Class.forName(strategyToApply);
            strategy = (IStrategy) classToUse.newInstance();**
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return strategy;
};

Consumer<Document> consumerStrategy = doc -> {
    IStrategy strategy = func.apply(doc);
    strategy.bookRequest(doc);
};
documents.stream()
    .forEach(consumerStrategy);
```

---

I finally found THE magic object. It is a good workaround when Spring object's lifecycle is not compliant with our own conception.

To use it, you just have to declare it with @Autowired :

```
@Autowired
private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireBeanFactory;
```

Note that the AutowireCapableBeanFactory is a Spring object you don't need to declare anywhere else !!

Then, to use it, simple (I designed a brand new service very different from what you saw above, but it's doing the same) :

```
public <T> T getStrategyToUse(Entity bookingCtr, Funder funder, StrategyEnum strategy) throws FunctionalException {
        String strategyToApply = null;
        strategyToApply = strategyDao.getClassToApply(bookingCtr, funder, strategy);
        Class<?> classToUse;
        try {
            classToUse = Class.forName(strategyToApply);
            T strat = (T) **autowireBeanFactory.getBean**(classToUse);
            return (T) strat;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            LOGGER.error("The indicated Strategy class was not found", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When loaded at runtime, the chosen class will be instanciated without any problem and ALL of its autowired objects won't be null anymore.

I hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of declaring the services as bean, you should declare a factory to map the dependencies, it will inspect the request before returning the concrete instance of the service to the injector.
take a look here:

https://grokonez.com/spring-framework/spring-core/use-spring-factory-method-create-spring-bean

Answer (score 0):

You can use below class to get Application Context and Beans statically

```
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;
    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }



}
```